# зеркалирование двух баз firebird

Tags: centos, репликация

Здравствуйте! Есть сервер, установлен Centos 7, на котором крутится несколько баз Firebird(объем мелкий, около 2 гб). из-за некоторых проблем с провайдером, бывают ситуации с провалами инета на несколько часов, иногда по несколько раз в месяц, чего допускать нельзя. Отсюда, собственно и вопрос - каким образом можно "зеркалировать" базы? например, в случае отказа основного сервера в бой вступал некий резервный, который стоит например дома. смотреть в сторону кластеров или репликации самих баз? как это работает? как реализуется?
и да, в гугле меня не забанили, просто по запросу "зеркалирование баз firebird" выдает тонну сайтов, причем даты постов в них от 2010года и старше. ну и куча вариантов, кто-то говорит что надо реплики, кто-то говорит что надо кластер. я запутался и прошу помощи тут) спасибо